# lAdIdAccess error, library not found

Tags: xcode

I've got this error and can't find anything about it (`-lAdIdAccess`):

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/macbook/Desktop/rapid ball/Rapid'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LBall'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LBall/googleanalytics'
ld: library not found for -lAdIdAccess
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What should I do?

Comment: fixed, reimport google analytics framework

Comment: just have not enoght reputation to comment -_-